# Is there a way to scrape data from a Microsoft Form survey?

Tags: excel, web-scraping, automation, data-analysis

I am trying to automate my survey analysis pipeline and would like to link the data from a Microsoft Form to an Excel sheet.
This is what the page looks like with results collected: [image]

But you have to click the open in excel to get the table of results. I was wondering if it would be possible to automate this so that it updates to capture all responses like once a day into an Excel sheet...this is what the output looks like when you click the button.
[image]

Any tools or tips would be great! I have some experience with R and Python so could implement that too...

Comment: If you only want update once a day, what's one click? In other words, not worth coding?

Comment: It's more to reduce the manual effort needed to analyse: you click which is fine as an isolated action but then you have to paste/format the data correctly into the analysis sheet so it updates which adds time if this has to be done every time someone adds a response. The updating automatically would eliminate the need to do this if that makes sense?

Comment: Yea that makes more sense. Google if excel has an object for msft forms?

Comment: Have you searched for scraping questions on here?

Answer (score 0):

Forms is already linked to an excel file, the "Open in Excel" button is a link to the excel file, which is saved either in files on your teams channel or in sharepoint.

The data is in a table automatically, and on sharepoint you can link between tables in different spreadsheets using the Data -> Get Data menu in excel.